# Sort Array From Database by Specific Key php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array called posts which consists of data from my database:

```
Array ( [post_id] => 29 [user_id] => 2 [post_image_url] => images/w8y46ot7bsr3cpxhunq9lg2dkmf05jzvei1a.jpg ) 1
Array ( [post_id] => 41 [user_id] => 2 [post_image_url] => images/czmhng9j7qr0ite4d2w6obvl3p1k5yasxuf8.jpg ) 1
Array ( [post_id] => 42 [user_id] => 2 [post_image_url] => images/rk5e7yc9xolsd4mbnp6t2w0zaquf8i1j3ghv.jpg ) 1
Array ( [post_id] => 39 [user_id] => 2 [post_image_url] => images/wuvhtcyksmza70641n3xb5l2rqgdp8jefoi9.jpg ) 1
Array ( [post_id] => 40 [user_id] => 14 [post_image_url] => images/41io86ln7f9gcz3ep2dmvrjbya5k0wsxqthu.jpg ) 1
```

I am trying to sort it from greatest to least by "post_id." Currently I am using the following code:

```
usort($posts, function($a, $b) { 
    return $a->post_id > $b->post_id ? -1 : 1;
});      
foreach($posts as $i){
     echo print_r($i). "<br>";
}
```

However, this is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is it "not working" ? (Also you access array elements with `[]`, not `->`; Add error reporting to get useful error messages)

Comment: add to the query `order by post_id desc`

Comment: @Rizier123 it is "not working" because the values are not sorted in descending order by "post_id." If you look at the array, you can see the order of post_id is all over the place and not in the correct order

Comment: @splash58 That will not make a difference because these values are retrieved based on information in another array. Doing that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accessing the element of the array with -> as opposed to []. Change this:

```
usort($posts, function($a, $b) { 
    return $a->post_id > $b->post_id ? -1 : 1;
});
```

To this:

```
usort($posts, function($a, $b) { 
    return $a[post_id] > $b[post_id] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's "correction" regarding accessing the array elements "means well", but it has syntax errors and will spew a bunch of these:

> **Notice**:  Use of undefined constant post_id - assumed 'post_id'

Furthermore his answer is more complicated than it needs to be.  Because you are sorting on the first column in your subarrays, you can just use `rsort()` and avoid a user-defined/custom sort method.  See for yourself:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2b14b5f7fd3ccc299d8174a60502caeba0b02746))

```
$posts=[
    ['post_id'=>29,'user_id'=>2,'post_image_url'=>'images/w8y46ot7bsr3cpxhunq9lg2dkmf05jzvei1a.jpg'],
    ['post_id'=>41,'user_id'=>2,'post_image_url'=>'images/czmhng9j7qr0ite4d2w6obvl3p1k5yasxuf8.jpg'],
    ['post_id'=>42,'user_id'=>2,'post_image_url'=>'images/rk5e7yc9xolsd4mbnp6t2w0zaquf8i1j3ghv.jpg'],
    ['post_id'=>39,'user_id'=>2,'post_image_url'=>'images/wuvhtcyksmza70641n3xb5l2rqgdp8jefoi9.jpg'],
    ['post_id'=>40,'user_id'=>14,'post_image_url'=>'images/41io86ln7f9gcz3ep2dmvrjbya5k0wsxqthu.jpg']
];
rsort($posts);

var_export($posts);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'post_id' => 42,
    'user_id' => 2,
    'post_image_url' => 'images/rk5e7yc9xolsd4mbnp6t2w0zaquf8i1j3ghv.jpg',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'post_id' => 41,
    'user_id' => 2,
    'post_image_url' => 'images/czmhng9j7qr0ite4d2w6obvl3p1k5yasxuf8.jpg',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'post_id' => 40,
    'user_id' => 14,
    'post_image_url' => 'images/41io86ln7f9gcz3ep2dmvrjbya5k0wsxqthu.jpg',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'post_id' => 39,
    'user_id' => 2,
    'post_image_url' => 'images/wuvhtcyksmza70641n3xb5l2rqgdp8jefoi9.jpg',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'post_id' => 29,
    'user_id' => 2,
    'post_image_url' => 'images/w8y46ot7bsr3cpxhunq9lg2dkmf05jzvei1a.jpg',
  ),
)
```